# how can I enlarge the boundaries of an html table

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

There are many tables nested inside as it showd in the following three images.
Please give an idea so that I can see the circled images fully in the third image..

ps: if you want any html code of o a part, I can share it here on request..

**Now**
**1**
[alt text http://img148.imageshack.us/img148/5750/21619773.jpg](http://img148.imageshack.us/img148/5750/21619773.jpg)

**2**
[alt text http://img408.imageshack.us/img408/2884/30078896.jpg](http://img408.imageshack.us/img408/2884/30078896.jpg)

**The Desired Html Page:**
[image]

**The Final Scene:**
[image]

Comment: This is entirely dependant on the existing html code/css.  It's just not possible to answer this by looking at a picture.  My advice would be to start from scratch and build the page back up again by adding in html/css from your existing page, until you get to the part you don't like, then change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having trouble understanding your question... if you're looking to enlarge a table, it might be as simple as setting the width.  However, you'll get more of what I think you're looking for if you're usings divs and/or floats instead of tables... tables tend to make your layout very rigid and un-fluid.

If you're looking to move content to different areas on the page after the expand, this can be done in javascript by manipulating the DOM... I can't be more specific without understanding what you're trying to do.

Can you post a picture of what you want it to look like afterwards?  The circles and arrows aren't giving me a clear understanding.

Comment: If you are using tables for each section, try explicitly setting the table cell widths to however wide you need them to be, and set the final cell width to 100% (I'm assuming you have a cell each for the labels, controls, the text in the middle, and the final set of labels/controls).  You'll have to set the width of each control to 100%, as well.

Using DIVs would make your layout more fluid and dynamic, but would involve a learning curve if you're not used to using them.  If you have the time, I recommend looking into them (I can point you to more info if you want)